# Extract array parts based on given keys in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. One containing the data and other contains the keys. So I have

```
$data = array(
    'name' => array('label' => 'Name:', 'value' => 'Genghis'),
    'age' => array('label' => 'Age:', 'value' => '67'),
    'weigh' => array('label' => 'Weigh in Kgs:', 'value' => '78')
);
```

and

```
$keys = array('name', 'age');
```

Now I want to extract only the `name` and `age` elements of `$data`. Some thing like this.

```
$extracted = somemethod($data, $keys);
var_export($extracted);
```

Output should be like this.

```
array(
    'name' => array(
        'label' => 'Name:', 
        'value' => 'Genghis',
    ),
    'age' => array(
        'label' => 'Age:',
        'value' => '67',
    ),
)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an `array_intersect_key()` function like this:

```
$data = array(...); // initial array as described
$retained_keys = array('name' => 'value not used', 'age' => 'value not used');

$filtered_array = array_intersect_key($data, $retained_keys);
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I would flip the OPs `$keys` array. `$retained_keys = array_flip( array( 'name', 'age'));`

Comment: @nickb Good suggestion if the $keys array is already defined and used for other purposed.  I just figured he might simply replace his `$keys` line with my `$retained_keys` definition if it only served this single purpose.

Comment: I found this already in manual. But didn't want to use it as it requires `array_flip`.

Comment: @GenghisKhan So why the concern over using array_flip?

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the keys, grab the array values, and return them:

```
function somemethod($data, $keys) {
    $return = array();
    foreach( $keys as $k) {
        $return[$k] = isset( $data[$k]) ? $data[$k] : null;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

The above adds 'null' when a field isn't found. You can modify the `foreach` loop to just skip the key when it's not found in the `$data` array, like this:

```
function somemethod($data, $keys) {
    $return = array();
    foreach( $keys as $k) {
        if( isset( $data[$k])) {
            $return[$k] = $data[$k];
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

**Edit:** To extend on Mike Brant's answer, `array_intersect_key()` can be used with `array_flip()` in a function to achieve the desired output:

```
function somemethod($data, $keys) {
    $keys = array_flip( $keys);
    return array_intersect_key($data, $keys);
}
```

Yes, it uses `array_flip()`, but the original `$keys` array is left unmodified, as a copy of that array is what gets flipped. So, you would still call this function with:

```
$extracted = somemethod( $data, array('name', 'age'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly onerous to write

```
$extracted = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if (isset($data[$key])) 
        $extracted[$key] = $data[$key];
}
```